# DNS Prefetch inside AWS Node.js Lambda

Tags: node.js, lambda, dns

I'm trying to prefetch DNS records inside a node.js Lambda function. I have instrumented my http requests (using Sentry) to show how long it takes for the socket to complete the dns lookup, and how long to establish the TCP connection.

When I run the function locally on my machine, it works - the http request takes almost no time at all to perform the lookup

But when I run the function on AWS Lambda, the DNS lookup still takes some time, as if the prefetch did not populate the lookup table. Here is the implementation:

```js
import dns from 'dns'

export const dnsPrefetch = url => {
  const address = new URL(url).hostname
  dns.lookup(address, { hints: dns.ADDRCONFIG }, () => {})
}
```

And then in a module, I might use it like so: `dnsPrefetch('https://url.to/graphql')`

Any ideas why the DNS prefetch is not working on Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap it inside a Promise:

```
async function lookupPromise(url){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dns.lookup(url, (err, address, family) => {
            if(err) reject(err);
            resolve(address);
        });
   });
}
```

Or use dns promises:

```
const dnsPromise = dns.promises;

dnsPromise.lookup(url)
```